# GetDynamicParameters() not invoked when another parameter is specified

Tags: c#, powershell, dynamic, parameters, powershell-cmdlet

I'm developing a PowerShell cmdlet `Get-Foo` in C# that defines a [dynamic parameter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878334(v=vs.85).aspx) `Bar`, that should show up only when the switch parameter `MySwitch` is specified. It also has other parameters `MyString`, `MyInt` and `MyBool`.

When I run the cmdlet, the dynamic parameter `Bar` shows up in tab completion just fine when I specify the switch parameter `MySwitch` along with either `MyString` or `MyInt` but not when I use it with `MyBool` (or any other parameter type).

Here's the code:

```
namespace MyCompany.Cmdlets
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "Foo")]
    public class GetFoo : PSCmdlet, IDynamicParameters
    {
        [Parameter]
        public string MyString { get; set; }

        [Parameter]
        public int MyInt { get; set; }

        [Parameter]
        public bool MyBool { get; set; }

        [Parameter]
        public SwitchParameter MySwitch { get; set; }

        public object GetDynamicParameters()
        {
            if (MySwitch.IsPresent)
            {
                context = new FooParameters();
                return context;
            }

            return null;
        }

        private FooParameters context;

        protected override void ProcessRecord() {}
    }

    public class FooParameters
    {
        [Parameter]
        public string Bar { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the dynamic parameters to show up when specifying the `MyBool` parameter (or a `MyObject` parameter)?

Comment: Just out of curiousity: why would you assign position to the switch parameter? It hardly makes any sense with this type - it is (by very nature) named parameter... Not sure if that would cause a problem with dynamic parameter, but I wouldn't be surprised.

Comment: I think, that PowerShell fail to fake bound value for `bool` parameter. It does not evaluate expressions when do completion resolution. For example, if you write `-MyString $a`, than in `GetDynamicParameters` it will be seen as `$a`, not as value of variable. So, possible, that PowerShell fail to convert string `$false` or `$true` to `bool` value.

Comment: @BartekB That was just one of the things I was playing around with to get this to work. It doesn't work even after I remove all the position attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the struct "SwitchParameter", I treat it like I do any other Boolean, for example:

```
if (MySwitchParameter)
{ 
   // la la la other stuff
}
```

GetDynamicParameters is tricky, however, you have two options with it in terms of Return 
Value: Return a object that represents your parameter *OR* return a 
RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary object. Think of the  RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary 
as a "CodeDom-Like" way of expressing your parameter.

Here is a possible rewrite to your Get-Foo Cmdlet, with emphasis on the Dynamic Parameter:

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "Foo",
    SupportsShouldProcess = true
    )]
public class GetFooCommand : PSCmdlet, IDynamicParameters
{
    // First things first: Lets try making a dictionary for our return 
    // value in our implementation of IDynamicParameter's 
    // GetDynamicParameters() method
    private RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary DynamicParameters;

    [Parameter]
    public string MyString { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public int MyInt { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    // Booleans are not as fun as SwitchParameters, IMHO
    public bool MyBool { get; set; }


    // Remember that SwitchParameter is really just a boolean (sort of), so 
    // it will default to 'false'
    [Parameter]
    public SwitchParameter MySwitch { get; set; }

    public object GetDynamicParameters()
    {
        // You only want this to run when the switch is flipped,
        // so try it this way and see if it works for you
        if (MySwitch)
        {
            // Create the dictionary. We will return this at the end because
            // **** spoiler alert **** it is an object :)
            var runtimeParameterDictionary = new RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary();


            // Lets make that parameter now. Your example doesn't specify any 
            // additional parameter attributes beyond the required "ParameterAttribute", 
            // so here we create an empty Attribute Collection
            var runtimeParameter = 
            new RuntimeDefinedParameter("Bar", typeof (string), new Collection<Attribute>());

            // With a new Parameter, lets add it to our dictionary. 
            runtimeParameterDictionary.Add("Bar", runtimeParameter);

            // Because we created a field for our dictionary way up top, we can assign it like I
            // illustrate below. This will enable easy, predictable results when we seek to 
            // extract the values from the dictionary at runtime.
            DynamicParameters = runtimeParameterDictionary;


            // Note: You can add as many parameters as you want this way, and that Is 
            // why I recommend it to you now. Coding the parameters as classes outside of the 
            // Cmdlet, and to some extent as embedded Classes,
            // within the Cmdlet Never really worked for me, so I feel your pain/frustration.

            return runtimeParameterDictionary;
        }

        return null; // Guess the user doesn't want that Bar afterall;
    }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        // We obviously want to sequester everything we are doing with the dynamic
        // parameters so a good-old-fashioned if.. then.. else... will suffice.
        if (MySwitch)
        {
            // Now we are here at the precipice of this DynamicParameter cmdlet.
            // Here is one way to get the value desired from the dynamic parameter.

            // Simply access it like a dictionary...
            var bar = DynamicParameters["Bar"].Value as string;

            // The reason we can do it this way is because we assigned our
            // beloved value to the local variable "DynmaicParameters"
            // in the GetDynamicParameters() method. We could care less about 
            // the return value, because if the 
            // switch is flipped, "DynamicParameters" will be our new best friend, and
            // it will have everything we need.

            WriteWarning("Your " + bar + " has been forwarded to an automatic voice messaging system ...");
        }


        WriteObject("Cheers was filmed before a live studio audience...");
        WriteObject(MyInvocation.BoundParameters);
    }
}
```